# PyPolars: Speed up apply function to find common elements

Tags: parallel-processing, apply, python-polars

I am trying to find common elements in a column of list wrt a reference cell. I could accomplish it with a small dataset but I face two problems. The speed is excruciatingly slow even for 25 rows of sample data (20.7 s ± 52 ms per loop), and I unable to find a faster implementation through `map` which can use parallelization unlike `apply` that works on a single thread.

The version that I have working right now is as follows:

```
>>> import polars as pl
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'animal': ['goat','tiger','goat','tiger','lion','goat','tiger','lion'], 'food': ['grass','rabbit','carrots','deer','zebra','water','water','water']})
>>> dl = df.groupby('animal').agg_list()
>>> dl
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬───────────────────────────────┐
│ animal ┆ food                          │
│ ---    ┆ ---                           │
│ str    ┆ list[str]                     │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════════╡
│ lion   ┆ ["zebra", "water"]            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ tiger  ┆ ["rabbit", "deer", "water"]   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ goat   ┆ ["grass", "carrots", "water"] │
└────────┴───────────────────────────────┘
>>>
>>> refn = dl['food'][1].to_numpy()
>>> dl['food'] = dl['food'].apply(lambda x: np.intersect1d(refn,x.to_numpy()))
>>> dl
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ animal ┆ food                      │
│ ---    ┆ ---                       │
│ str    ┆ object                    │
╞════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ lion   ┆ ['water']                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ tiger  ┆ ['deer' 'rabbit' 'water'] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ goat   ┆ ['water']                 │
└────────┴───────────────────────────┘
>>>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python/numpy/sets for memberships in polars you are most of the time on the wrong path. This counts actually for using `apply` in general.

Let's start of where you left. You took the `1`st index of column `"food"` which has dtype `List`. So that gives us a `Series` assigned to `refn`.

```py
dl = df.groupby('animal', maintain_order=True).agg_list()
refn = dl['food'][1]
refn
```

```
shape: (3,)
Series: 'food' [str]
[
    "rabbit"
    "deer"
    "water"
]
```

### Option 1 (slower)

This solution does an `O(n)` search in every elemnt, so this is likely not the fastest.

We simply `filter` the original `df` with membership of `refn` and the aggregate the result again.

```py
(df.filter(pl.col("food").is_in(refn))
   .groupby("animal").agg_list()
)
```

### Option 2 (fastest)

A better option, is using a `semi` join. A `semi` join filters the `DataFrame` by membership in another `DataFrame`, sounds like something we want!

```py
(df.join(refn.to_frame(), on="food", how="semi")
   .groupby("animal").agg_list()
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to Polars and there is a lot to learn. It (2nd approach) works on the example. I am missing some on my data in which the lists have over 10-20K strings. I am looking into it and get back in a while.

Comment: The second code works faster and was what I was looking for. Thank you.